# Passing a Boolean pointer from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to call an objective-C method from swift. The method signature is:

```
-(BOOL)getPassThroughSync:(BOOL *)enabled error:(NSError **)error;
```

I am not yet able to pass in a Boolean pointer. Here is what I have so far:

```
var passThrough: Bool?
    if scanner.getPassThroughSync(&passThrough, error: nil) {
}
```

This does not compile due to an invalid argument list.

Similarly, I want to call

```
-(BOOL)getUSBChargeCurrent:(int *)current error:(NSError **)error;
```

requiring an int pointer.

What am I missing?

Comment: Um, &error is not an NSError **. Also, is BOOL the same as Bool (I don't use Swift)?

Comment: I think you would need to define what you mean by 'the same'. Conceptually yes, but I'm not qualified to describe the differences in language implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Eventually, with help from the comments on other answers, the following worked:

```
var passThrough: ObjCBool = false
if scanner.getPassThroughSync(&passThrough, error: nil) {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = passThrough ? "Yes" : "No"
}
```

Similarly,

```
var current: Int32 = 0
if scanner.getUSBChargeCurrent(&current, error: nil) {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(current) + "mA"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for is in the *Pointers* section of [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11). Essentially, you have to declare a pointer type: `Type *` maps to `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>`.

To access the value stored in the pointer, use its `memory` property.

For more details on `UnsafeMutablePointer` see [this document](http://swiftdoc.org/type/UnsafeMutablePointer/).

Comment: I've tried declaring `var passThrough: UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>` but the compiler still complains.

Comment: `passThrough.memory`, I believe... See [this document](http://swiftdoc.org/type/UnsafeMutablePointer/) for details.

Comment: I think you need to define `passThrough` as an unsafe mutable pointer to an _optional_ boolean, `var passThrough: UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool?>`. I might be wrong; I can't test any of my suggestions at the moment.